# Why could return nullptr when returnType is a nested struct in class?

Tags: c++

In slang project, I find this function definition below:

```cpp
// returnType is Preprocessor::MacroDef, which is a nested struct in class Preprocessor
Preprocessor::MacroDef Preprocessor::findMacro(Token directive) {
    std::string_view name = directive.valueText().substr(1);
    if (!name.empty() && name[0] == '\\')
        name = name.substr(1);

    auto it = macros.find(name);
    if (it == macros.end())
        return nullptr;  // <-- here return nullptr
    return it->second;
}
```

I am really confused.

below code is all about `MacroDef` struct

```cpp
// A saved macro definition; if it came from source code, we will have a parsed
// DefineDirectiveSyntax. Otherwise, it's an intrinsic macro and we'll note that here.
struct MacroDef {
    const syntax::DefineDirectiveSyntax* syntax = nullptr;
    MacroIntrinsic intrinsic = MacroIntrinsic::None;
    bool builtIn = false;

    MacroDef() = default;
    MacroDef(const syntax::DefineDirectiveSyntax* syntax) : syntax(syntax) {}
    MacroDef(MacroIntrinsic intrinsic) : intrinsic(intrinsic), builtIn(true) {}

    bool valid() const { return syntax || intrinsic != MacroIntrinsic::None; }
    bool isIntrinsic() const { return intrinsic != MacroIntrinsic::None; }
    bool needsArgs() const;
};
```

Comment: The implicit converting constructor `MacroDef(const syntax::DefineDirectiveSyntax* syntax)` does the job.

Answer (score 3):

The implicit converting constructor `MacroDef(const syntax::DefineDirectiveSyntax* syntax)` does its job.

The readability with a such practice suffers, you have experienced it. I would make the explicit constructor:

```
  explicit MacroDef(const syntax::DefineDirectiveSyntax* syntax);
```

and this instead of `nullptr`:

```
  return {};
```